# How to change the background color of WebView in React native?

Tags: react-native

My WebView first loads and TouchableOpacity is pressed after it. Can I do this after the background webview has changed without restarting the webview?

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View,Text} from 'react-native'

export default class TestScreen extends Component {
render() {
return  (
    <View >
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={/*what is the function that changes the background color of the webview after loading it (but without reloading the Webview)*/}>
         <WebView>
       </TouchableOpacity>

     </View>
  );
}}
```

Answer (score 8):

Yes. You can. You can actually change the background color of the webview by doing this.

Add a style prop in the WebView opening tag. like this

```js
<WebView 
  style={{
    backgroundColor: 'green'
  }}
/>
```

this sets the background of the webview to green.

Answer (score 6):

No, you cannot change the background color of a webview, but you can use another view with your background color cover on your web view.

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, StyleSheet, WebView, ActivityIndicator} from 'react-native';

export default class YourComponent extends React.PureComponent{

    state = {
        loading: true,
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <WebView
                    source={html}
                    onLoadEnd={() => {
                        this.setState({loading: false});
                    }}
                />
                {
                    this.state.loading && (
                        <View style={{
                            ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
                            backgroundColor: '#000000',  // your color 
                            alignItems: 'center',
                            justifyContent: 'center',
                        }}>
                            <ActivityIndicator />
                        </View>
                    )
                }
            </View>
        )

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the background of a React Native Webview is not possible unless you add some script/style that will manipulate the HTML contents for instance:

```
 <WebView
     scalesPageToFit={false}
     originWhitelist={["*"]}
     source={{ html: `<style>body{background-color:#000;}span{background-color:#000!important;color:#fff!important}</style>${$content}` }}
      />
```

The above code changes the body background color to black, the text background color to black, and the text color to white.
Remember HTML content styling depends on the content tags.