# How to force disable android dark mode in React Native

Tags: react-native, android-darkmode

I made one app in react-native using

```
"react-native": "0.62.0",

"react": "16.11.0",
```

as I put my android device in dark mode, my UI designs get disturbed so i want to make it disable for now.

please help.

Comment: what exact part of you UI is getting disturbed? Statubar? footer? buttons?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yr7JFnCVQT_QEq5aUODhw0qjF1X4W1jB/view?usp=sharing , I have managed it with some images also having some content pages loaded in  <webView>  so both  creating issue

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53748973/how-to-change-the-background-color-of-webview-in-react-native - this sounds like a solution to <Webview> dark mode.
Also you can change colors of Statusbar or completely remove statusbar

Answer (score 17):

You can disable force dark mode in android by adding this line in your `styles.xml` in your android folder

```xml
<item name="android:forceDarkAllowed">false</item>
```

Like this

```xml
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:forceDarkAllowed">false</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

You need to run the app again after doing these changes since these changes are native level.

**Edit:** If you get error about target API use it like this

```xml
<item name="android:forceDarkAllowed" tools:targetApi="q">false</item>
```

Comment: not working at all

Comment: can you share code of your styles.xml, I use this in my every project

Comment: Didn't work for me.

Comment: in <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar"> replace DayNight by Light

Comment: Remember to remove android/app/build and reinstall android app

Answer (score 16):

File path: `android/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml`

change

`<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">`

to

`<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">`

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Beast answer. Thank you.

Also kudos to @https://stackoverflow.com/users/9176532/a-sana

Answer (score 10):

For IOS change your info.plist

```
<key>UIUserInterfaceStyle</key>
    <string>Light</string>
```

Answer (score 2):

You Can `Appearance` hook for it.

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { Appearance } from 'react-native';
const App = () => {
  useEffect(() => Appearance.setColorScheme('light'),
  [])
  return <View>
    <Text>Some Text<Text>
  </View>
}
```

Comment: thanks! i think this is the proper way instead of changing the xml file, because if u change the xml file some libs maybe has their own way to read the dark mode state, in my case i use react-native-paper, i already edit the xml, yes some component prevented to be dark but my component from rn paper still dark

Answer (score 0):

It's complicade because you can try many things but if you buy a theme of other developer maybe the code have lines to force the dark mode. I bought  a theme a have this lines, like this:

```
export const useTheme = () => {
 const isDarkMode = useColorScheme() === 'dark';
 const forceDark = useSelector(state => state.application.force_dark);
 const themeStorage = useSelector(state => state.application.theme);
 const listTheme = ThemeSupport.filter(item => item.theme == themeStorage);
 const theme = listTheme.length > 0 ? listTheme[0] : DefaultTheme;

 if (forceDark) {
   return {theme: theme.dark, colors: theme.dark.colors}; <--- change here
 }
 if (forceDark === false) {
   return {theme: theme.light, colors: theme.light.colors};
 }
 return isDarkMode
   ? {theme: theme.dark, colors: theme.dark.colors} <----- change here
   : {theme: theme.light, colors: theme.light.colors};
};
```

So I change dark to ligth and solved my problem.