# Notification icon in dark mode

Tags: react-native, expo, android-notifications

There is a problem with the notification icon in the dark theme in the application on Android 12+. The application was created at Expo (SDK 45). In a light theme, the color is displayed correctly, but in a dark theme, it changes. How to make color not change? Or what is the color changing process?

```
 minSdkVersion 21
 targetSdkVersion 31
```

The notification icon is set to blue (#192BC2). In a light theme it is displayed correctly, and in a dark theme it turns purple. Setting the color in color.xml (night) didn't help

[image: Light Theme]
[image: Dark Theme]

Comment: Have you tried to disable dark mode for just the image in question?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/68126532/361842

Comment: Didn't work for me

Comment: Have you found a solution to this issue ?